# Why would my variables titled "percA" and "percB" be coming out as "0.00.." no matter what?

Tags: c

```
int gamesTotal, winsA, lossA, winsB, lossB, magicNum, gamesLeft;
double percA, percB, percToClinch;

percA = (double) (winsA / (winsA + lossA));
percB = (double) (winsB / (winsB + lossB));
```

(More lines of my program can be included if no problem is found here; only included lines relevant to the problem.)

Comment: Cast `winsA`, `winsB`, `lossA`, and `lossB` as `double` in the operation.

Comment: integer division A / B with A < B gives zero.

Comment: Minus one for jumping straight into difficult code without attempting to understand simple code first.

Comment: multiply int variable by 1.0. Example: percA = (double) (winsA *1.0 / (winsA + lossA));

Comment: To display percent, `double` not even needed.  `printf("%d%%\n", winsA*100 / (winsA + lossA);`  or use `(winsA*100 + (winsA + lossA)/2)/(winsA + lossA)` for a rounded answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your cast in the wrong place.  You need to cast one of the operands of the division operator.  Otherwise, you'll be doing integer division instead of floating point division.

```
percA = (double)winsA / (winsA + lossA);
percB = (double)winsB / (winsB + lossB);
```

You're getting zero for the result because you're dividing integers, and the denominator is larger than the numerator.  The integer part is 0 and the fractional part is truncated.